# XCUITest wait for element that may appear

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I’m getting my head around using `XCUITest`, and running into a situation where I’m trying to dismiss an alert that “may” appear.

It’s a tutorial that pops up the first time out user goes into the photo editor, but it only pops up on first launch. Since we don’t want to reset the simulator between each test (for speed reasons), this alert “may” or “may not” appear on any given test.

I’ve been using `waitWithExpectation` for other things like this, but there won’t be an expectation if the alert isn’t there. I really want to avoid putting the thread to sleep.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to handle an alert on the gallery access, try this:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Access Your Photos") { (alert) -> Bool in
       if alert.buttons["OK"].exists {
            alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
            return true
       }
       return false
}
app.tap()
```

it works if the alert exists or not.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a custom alert :(

Comment: Custom alert in the sense that it doesn't inherit from UIAlertController? What UIKit class does it inherit from, if any?

Comment: please post some line of code. from this custom alert and you current UITest

Comment: It’s a UIView subclass.